# Why does new Rails db migration file start with datestamp instead of sequence number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Whenever I use script/generate to generate a new scaffold for a change to my Rails database, the new migration file is prepended by a datestamp (e.g. 200903140912_create_users.rb) instead of a sequence number (e.g. 004_create_users.rb).

I then have to manually change the file name to fit in with the rest of the migration files.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

System: Mac OS X Leopard 10.5.6
Rails: v2.2.2
Ruby: v1.8.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was introduced in Rails 2.1. According to the [migrations docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#whatsinaname), you can revert it by setting `config.active_record.timestamped_migrations` to `false` in `config/environment.rb`.

Comment: Voting up, but for accuracy: timestamp migrations were introduced in 2.1, with the option to disable (confusingly) introduced in 2.1.1. Also worth noting that although the OP was concerned the timestamp needed to be changed, mixed old & new style migrations would work  fine without renaming.

Comment: FINALLY! Yes! I always use nano for my migration files because its quick and easy, but after a while I end up pecking my way through the timestamp! thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why they made the decision, but I can tell you how it's made my life easier. On a team it was common for two people to create migrations at roughly the same time. If the last production migration was 007 then both of the new ones would be 008. The second person to commit would have a headache on their hands trying to sort it out, and the timestamps make that conflict a lot less likely.

Answer (score 2):

The decision was made because when people worked together on the same project they would often try to create a migration with their new changes. This would lead to the issue where two people were working on the same project making separate changes but both generating a migration with the same number. The Rails core team decided to change it to a UTC timestamp since it's way less likely (but still possible!) that two (or more) developers would be creating a migration in the same second, rather than the same sequence.

Comment: This has always seemed like a problem best fixed with better communication instead of harder-to-read filenames. When you have two people working on migrations at the same time, they should be in constant contact anyway, because the migration *created* first may not be the one you want *run* first.

Comment: It's not the matter of the migrations running in order, generally two people won't work on the same table at the same time and have tasks dependent of the other. The problem is that when two people create migrations they BOTH have the same sequence number which then makes rake db:migrate fail.

Comment: @RyanBigg, Do you have any links to a discussion about this decision on a mailing list or a forum or something. That would have great value in this answer.

Comment: Sorry, no I don't have that info @Jarl. It's mostly hearsay and from personal experience.

Answer (score 2):

It is also worth mentioning that using the UTC timestamp helps with sequence that migrations are run when the developers might be in separate time zones.